# How can I perform this MySQL join operation?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables like below;

**tablea**

[image: tablea]

**tableb**

[image: tableb]

In tablea, I have `prodid` and `tagid`. Its a composite primary key. `prodid` acts as a foreign key, pointing to tableb. In tableb, I have `prodid`, `form`, and `link`. `prodid` of tablea points to `link` of tableb. What I want is, if I give input like array, like, `A9rLRawV,mi9rLmZW` , I want output as;

```
broe4AMb
rEEtK9gt
```

I have a query like;

```
SELECT p.link AS links
FROM tablea t
INNER JOIN tableb p ON t.prodid = p.link
WHERE t.tagid IN ('A9rLRawV','mi9rLmZW')
GROUP BY p.prod HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

But, it returns result like;

```
broe4AMb
rEEtK9gt
rEEtK9Hh
```

But what I expect should not contain `rEEtK9Hh`. I am expecting the result;

```
broe4AMb
rEEtK9gt
```

This is because, I want product, which has both `A9rLRawV` and `mi9rLmZW`. Here, `rEEtK9Hh` (or prod `Bhc5y488`) in table b has only `A9rLRawV`, which I don't want.

How can I do this? I use PHP + MySQL

Comment: Can you setup a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: You have no p.drug field in your sample tables, and since you're grouping on it, obviously the grouping with rEEtK9Hh is satisfied for it.

Comment: @MarcB its prod, my mistake. So what Should I do to get the expected result?

Comment: did you test this query? you say in your description that tablea.prodid links to tableb.link but in  your query you join on tablea.tagid = tableb.link?

Comment: Why you do not expected rEEtK9Hh in result?. it's possible with the data and relationship in your example. Any logical base to exclude rEEtK9Hh ?

Comment: In addition to the example, please also *explain* what you're trying to do with your query, i.e. how should the output depend on the given input. As your question is phrased, `SELECT 'broe4AMb', 'rEEtK9gt'` would technically be a valid answer -- it gives the correct answer for the single input you've mentioned in your example.

Comment: Wrong inner join field that you were using, could you please try with prodid as you mentioned in your question ? t.prodid=p.link

Comment: Updated my question. Please check and comment for more info

Comment: Part of what makes understanding your question so difficult is the completely arbitrary nature of the data.  Could you provide a sample of what you have and what you want to do that is human readable?  You may even discover that the answer presents itself to you when you do this.

Answer (score 0):

FIRST APPROACH [SOLVED]:

Your error is here:

```
INNER JOIN tableb p ON t.tagid = p.link
```

You need to use your JOIN with prodid, something like this:

```
INNER JOIN tableb p ON t.prodid = p.link
```

SECOND APPROACH:

You don't need to group the 'prod' field because always are unique on 'tableb'. You need to group with 'link' field.

Comment: I updated my answer. You don't need to group the 'prod' field because always are unique on 'tableb'. You need to group with 'link' field.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you just look at your tableA you could directly retrieve the prodid by using the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function in MySQL.

For example produce a virtual `SELECT` table where you can directly compare on the existing pair (keypair in this example).

```
SELECT prodid, GROUP_CONCAT(tableA.tagid) as keypair FROM `tableA` GROUP BY prodid;
```

Would return:

```
prodid    keypair
--------  -----------------
4c4fedf7  OMoy3H0a,yiWDGB4D
broe4AMb  A9rLRawV,mi9rLmZW
nhrtK9ce  yEsBoYLj
rEEtK9gt  A9rLRawV,mi9rLmZW
rEEtK9Hh  A9rLRawV,msBWz8CQ
```

The FINAL query could be something like:

```
SELECT prodid 
   FROM (SELECT prodid, GROUP_CONCAT(tableA.tagid) as keypair FROM `tableA` GROUP BY prodid) AS T 
   WHERE keypair = 'A9rLRawV,mi9rLmZW'
```

Returning:

```
prodid
--------
broe4AMb
rEEtK9gt
```